# [BlogEngine.NET] Compression error

Tags: web-hosting, blog, godaddy, compression

I have a [blogengine.net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) website hosted on godaddy and I'm having issues when viewing it with Firefox and Chrome. On Firefox I get this error :

```
Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown 
because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
```

On Google Chrome however, I only get a white page like if there was nothing that would load.

I'm wondering if it's the server (GoDaddy hosting), the website or both together that is causing this problem. When I run it directly from VS2010 I don't get any errors.

What could cause that and how could I solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source](http://www.deepakdhakal.com/post/2009/05/11/e2809ccontent-encoding-errore2809d-while-using-blogenginenet.aspx)

> While using BlogEngine.net you may run
>   into “content encoding error” “The
>   page you are trying to view cannot be
>   shown because it uses an invalid or
>   unsupported form of compression” this
>   error, to resolve this, find
>
> ```
> <add name=”CompressionModule” type=”BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.CompressionModule, BlogEngine.Core”/>
> ```
>
> in your web.config file and comment
>   this line of code. This error mostly
>   arrives when you host blogengine.net
>   site on GoDaddy.

Comment: There are multiple occurence of this line. Make sure to comment both of them.

Comment: I wanted to add that this also happens with Azure - and it drove me crazy b/c it didnt kick in until I enabled the DbBlogProvider to save blog posts to SQL Server instead of Xml.